# PHP, Python - Python get input from php plugin

Tags: python, php

I am working on a wordpress website and I vould like to use Python on one part of the backend. There is a file path which I need to change quite often and I vould like to change that in PHP code instead on Python code. Meaning that I want to insert file path in PHP script which runs the python code instead of in Python code.

Here is my Python line of code:

```
path = ('my_path')
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

So Inside this php file I want to insert a line in which I can put a file path here insead of in Python code. But i do need this path in my Python script so I need some sort of connection between php and python script.